# How do I require a ruby file from child directory

Tags: ruby, rake, require

I have the following structure

```
tests
  specific tests
    first_test.rb
  more tests
    second_test.rb
 test_helper.rb
```

Now I am trying to require test_helper in both first_test and second_test. The following works

> require '../test_helper.rb'

and from command line I should be under specific tests and execute

```
ruby first_test.rb
```

How can I get more flexibility ie. I want to be in any directory and execute these tests. Currently I am getting 'no such file'. This is not a rails app but in rails I could simply do require 'test_helper.rb'

Bonus points for making this work with rake.

Answer (score 1):

Put your test_helper and other helpers in a separate directory like

```
/home/XXX/projects/test_project/lib/
```

or wherever you like and use base directory like

```
Dir["base/path/to/your/helper/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```

or from my above example

```
Dir["/home/XXX/projects/test_project/lib/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```

Thats it.
Now add this line to the beginning of every test you want to run separately from any directory.And forget about the directory issue.